# WiX Bootstrapper Include OpenXMLSDK

Tags: wix

I have strange situation, it seems that OpenXMLSDK msi which is included in WiX bootraper as prerequisite is not installing on user PC. Bellow is my project structure. Any parameter which should I pass to MsiPackage ?

```
    <Chain> 
      <PackageGroupRef Id="OpenXMLSDK"/>     
      <MsiPackage Id="MyProject" SourceFile="$(var.MyProjectInstaller.TargetPath)"/>
     </Chain>
    </Bundle>

 <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="OpenXMLSDK">
      <MsiPackage Id="OpenXMLSDK"
               DisplayName="Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office"
               DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/3/553C731E-9333-40FB-ADE3-E02DC9643B31/OpenXMLSDKV25.msi"
               Compressed="yes"
               Cache="yes"
               Permanent="yes"
               Vital="yes"
               SourceFile=".\Prerequisites\OpenXMLSDKV25.msi"
               Name ="Prerequisites\OpenXMLSDKV25.msi"/>
    </PackageGroup>

    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Note: It seems that the OpenXML is actually installing but it is not visible in Control Panel Add/Remove programms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an MsiPackage to be visible in Add/Remove Programs, then you need to set the `Visible` attribute to `yes`.